# Passing Values from a Servlet to a JSP

Tags: java, forms, jakarta-ee, servlets

I want to select a User from a list, and show the values in the input fields (so an admin can change them)

a JSP has a form to select a user out of a User List:

```
         <form action="UserSelectionController" method="POST">
             <select name="selectedUser" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                <%
                  Object[] userList_ref = UserListService.getUserList();
                  for (int i = 0; i < userList_ref.length; i++) {%>
                        <option  size="5" value="<%=userList_ref[i]%>">           <%=userList_ref[i]%></option> <% }%>
             </select>
        </form>
```

the UserSelectionController reads out values from a database and looks like this: (only the dopost method here)

```
Protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    this.connectToDataBase();

    Statement stmt_ref = null;
    try {
        stmt_ref = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet results_ref = stmt_ref.executeQuery("SELECT salutation,firstname,lastname,street,houseNr,zip,city,country,email,password FROM User WHERE email = '" + request.getParameter("selectedUser") + "'");

        while (results_ref.next()){
            salutation = results_ref.getString("salutation");
            firstname = results_ref.getString("firstname");
            lastname = results_ref.getString("lastname");
            street = results_ref.getString("street");
            houseNr = results_ref.getInt("houseNr");
            zip = results_ref.getInt("zip");
            city = results_ref.getString("city");
            country = results_ref.getString("country");
            email = results_ref.getString("email");
            password = results_ref.getString("password");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(UserSelectionController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println ("Paramter SelectedUser: "+request.getParameter("selectedUser"));
    System.out.println ("Firstname: "+firstname);

    response.sendRedirect(AbsoluteTerms.DOMAIN_USER_SETTINGS);
}
```

it also Uses getter Methods to bring the values back to the JSP:

```
    public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}
```

the system out println tests show the correct Value in the servlet. The Redirect goes to the same JSP where the data came from. Back in the JSP I want to show the value in the input field:

```
   <jsp:useBean id="userSelection" class="servlets.UserSelectionController" />
   <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<% userSelection.getFirstname();%>" />
```

Sadly here the values are null. What can I do. Any clue would be great.
best regards, Daniel

Comment: I'd start by putting your mouse above the `servlets` tag below your question until a black box pops up. Then, click therein the *info* link.

Answer (score 2):

You are using your servlet, as a dto. This is not good.

Create another pojo, it will be a [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object). It will just have member variable that are strings, and accopmanying getters/setters. Populate its members with the result of your query, and put dto into session :

`request.setAttribute("userSelectionDTO",userSelectionDTO);`

then change the jsp so it references the dto:

```
 <jsp:useBean id="userSelection" class="servlets.UserSelectionDTO" />
 <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<% userSelection.getFirstname();%>"
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp) may be useful, and use [JSTL](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html) in the jsp.

Comment: can you tell me where? in the controller (servlet) or on the jsp? thanks

Comment: what does the line request.setAttribute("userSelectionDTO"), userSelectionDTO); does exactly? There is no session set, its not working sadly.

Comment: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<% userSelection.getFirstname();%>" this is still null

Comment: you have either not set the request attribute, or you have failed to intialize the firstname member variable of the userSelection object

Comment: a System.out.println ("request.getAttribute: "+request.getAttribute("user_ref")); shows the attribute exists and is not null, same is if I output the firstname member variable. Just on the JSP page its null.

Comment: Scriptlets do not share the same scope as taglibs/EL. Use EL. You also don't need jsp:useBean.

Comment: with EL you mean Expression Language? what to use instead of jsp:useBean? UserSelectionDTO us_ref = new UserSelectionDTO() ? I really appreciate some more Information cause this is still not working. I really appreciate your help but this problem is driving me nuts right now.

Comment: hey, hold on, I added a "=" behind the "%" in this line value="<% userSelection.getFirstname();%> now the input field shows "null" instead of nothing, very cool, but its still not getting the right value, thanks anyway. Maybe someone can solve the rest of this?

Answer (score 0):

Do as NimChimpsky wrote or just keep the selected user in http session.