# forEach iterator tag

Tags: java, json, jsp

I have a for each loop that it works fine in the following way:

```
<c:forEach begin="0" end="10" varStatus="status">'+
      <td><div id="text<c:out value="${status.index}"/>"> </div></td>
</c:forEach>'+
```

I have the following code in the Action class. I just want to pass the listSize in the place of end="10" in the above loop.

```
Vector<String> l1 = new Vector<String>();
Vector<String> v1 = new Vector<String>();
l1.add("listSize");
v1.add(String.valueOf(list.length));
for (int i=0;i<list.length;i++){
    if (notEmpty(list[i].getText())){
    l1.add("text"+i);
    v1.add(list[i].getText());
         }
}response.getWriter().print(JSONUtils.toJSON(new Collection[]{l1}, new Collection[]{v1}));
```

does any one has idea?

Answer (score 1):

use `<c:set>` to set a variable (from within JSP/JSTL) or add the variable to `requestScope` first (in Java part of JSP), and then refer to the variable via requestScope.variable.

then use `end="${variable}"` in the `<c:forEach>` tag.

Regards.

Comment: I have tried the <c:set> and it's showing the error 'null' is null or not an object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set "listSize" attribute to the request, which will contain a size of the list.

All answers are here: [Pass variables from servlet to jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp)

Comment: I have set the attribute to the request as shown below. request.getSession().setAttribute("listSize", list.length);

Comment: And in the jsp using the <c:set var="count" value="${sessionScope.listSize}"/> and used this count variable in the end attribute. (i.e end="{count}")

Comment: You could just use end="${listSize}". If I did help you, please mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I'm using the end attribute as end="${listSize}". When i typed the code I missed the $. sorry for the Inconvinience. Is any other suggestions pls.