# Servlet-Servlet-Jsp redirecting

Tags: java, jsp

I'm developing an application in JAVA where a servlet is taking the inputs from a JSP page. After inserting the values in db it will redirect to another servlet. Then the 2nd servlet will dispatch a JSP page with an ArrayList. But I can't redirect from the 2nd servlet to the JSP page. The ArrayList is going to the JSP page but the page is not showing anything. I'm using NetBeans 6.8. 
I'll be thankful  if anyone can solve this problem.

**Code for 1st Servlet:**

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet1?id="+id);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

**Code for 2nd Servlet:**

```
request.setAttribute("list",list);
String url="test2.jsp";
RequestDispatcher v=request.getRequestDispatcher(""+url+"");
v.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: Show some code preferably from your 2nd servlet.

Comment: Add your code to understand the exact problem.

Comment: @Sankha: In you question you area saying two different things which looks ambiguus to me:
1.)But I can't redirect from the 2nd servlet to the JSP page.
2.)The ArrayList is going to the JSP page but the page is not showing anything
Please make it clear if the browser is going to the second jsp or not.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm redirecting from 1st servlet to the 2nd servlet with the "id" which is used to fetch some data from DB which is stored in an ArrayList nd the 2nd servlet will redirect to a JSP page with the ArrayList.

Comment: I've put a System.out.println("list values::"+list.get(0)); in the final JSP page. It is working and print the value which I can see in the output console in Netbeans. But the page is not displayed.

Comment: @MayankSharma I'm not getting any error

Comment: put some sys out statements in your code. try to find out till what point the code is executing

Comment: @MayankSharma the 2nd servlet is working properly when I'm accessing it directly. But when I'm accessing it through another servlet the problem is arises.

Answer (score 0):

try this on 2nd servlet ..

```
request.setAttribute("list",list);
String url="test2.jsp";
RequestDispatcher v=request.getRequestDispatcher(url);
v.forward(request, response);
```

On jsp page ...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="item">
        ${item}<br>
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing exception. I've put a System.out.println("list values::"+list.get(0)); in the final JSP page. It is working and print the value which I can see in the output console in Netbeans. But the page is not displayed.

Comment: you can try JSTL on your jsp page.

Comment: here is link for JSTL .. [link](stackoverflow.com/questions/2148658/java-list-use-through-use-of-jstl-cforeach)

Comment: Actly, the 2nd servlet is working properly when I'm accessing it directly. But when I'm accessing it through another servlet the problem is arises.

Comment: umm ... try response.sendRedirect("/path/to/your.jsp");

Comment: here is something i fund for you .. [link] http://stackoverflow.com/a/3608917/1576040

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MySqlConnection {

    Connection c;

    public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbName = "ignite292";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "root";
        Class.forName(driver); // You don't need to call it EVERYTIME btw. Once during application's startup is more than enough.
        c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, user, password);
        return c;
    }

    public void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if (!c.isClosed()) {
                c.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First things, If you are using any redirect mechanism, It should not be in RequestScope. It must be in Session or Context Scope(Based on your Requirement). So , the resultant code for 2nd Servlet may as follow

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("list",list);
String url="/test2.jsp";
RequestDispatcher v=request.getRequestDispatcher(""+url+"");
v.forward(request, response);
```

Try with this Code.

Answer (score 0):

Sankha,

You can add those objects into session object. and you can use that session obj in any jsp and servlet.

suppose you have an arrayList Obj which have some data objects. and you are trying redirecting your servlet to jsp OR servlet to servlet.
eg:-

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet1?id="+id);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
request.setAttribute("list",list); // **Insted of using request object use session implicit object**.
String url="test2.jsp";
RequestDispatcher v=request.getRequestDispatcher(""+url+"");
v.forward(request, response);
```

Please refer below code to sort out your problem.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/Servlet1?id="+id);
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
**session.setAttribute("list",list);** 
String url="test2.jsp";
RequestDispatcher v=request.getRequestDispatcher(""+url+"");
v.forward(request, response);
```

And get this list object by using

**List dataList = session.getAttribute("list");**

Hope this will help you.