# Passing calculation result to JSP page

Tags: java, forms, servlets

Index.jsp takes two input number and after submit the request go to Operation.java. It has a radio button to select Operation. Both inputs and radio button are submitted to Operation.java.

```
<body>
    <h1>Easy way to do fast operation</h1>
    <form action="Operation">
        First number::<input type="text" name="firstno"></input></br></br>
        Second number::<input type="text" name="Secondno"></input></br></br>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="add">Add</input>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="substract">Subtract</input>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="mul">Multiply</input>
        <input type="radio" name="option" value="divide">Divide</input>
        </br></br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>    
    <%if(request.getAttribute("res")!=null){%>                   
        The result is ::${res}
    <%}%>
</body>
```

Operation.java(Servlet) takes value from input button and do calculation based on the radio button click. It will calculate the result.

```
int result1=0;
int n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("firstno"));
int n2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Secondno"));
String radio=request.getParameter("option");
if(radio.equals("add"))
{
    result1=n1+n2;
}
 else if(radio.equals("substract"))
{
    result1=n1-n2;
}
else if(radio.equals("mul"))
{
    result1=n1*n2;
}

       request.setAttribute("res", result1);
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =      request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

After calculation I want to show the result on the index.jsp. How can I do that?

Comment: use request.setAttribute("result1Name",result1);

Comment: @gjman2 But I want to get the result after clicking on submit button.
not before. In this case in Index Page I always get the result value.

Comment: So after edited, it is working?

Comment: @gjman2 Ya it working.

Comment: btw, do u know jstl? @ashish

Comment: avoid scriplet, use jstl :)

Comment: @gjman2 I know but only basic. can you change above scriptlet code into jstl

Comment: i have made changes on your codes with jstl, but u must have jstl library in your project

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to communicate between servelt and jsp.

1)Through request.

2)Through `session`.

In your case,request level communication is enough.Dealing with  session is little tricky,especially when you are not aware what it do.

In your servlet

```
            int n1=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("firstno"));
            int n2=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("Secondno"));
```

Those twolines causes `nullpointer exception.`  if they are null.

Put null checks.

Then   change the form action,it might be  `<form action="/Operation">`.

Then from there set result to that  request as a `attribute.`

Dispatch to the same `jsp`

get the request attribute  in jsp.

Print there.

```
request.setAttribute("name", "value");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Read more :

- [Pass variables from servlet to jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp)
- [Servlet JSP Communication](http://javapapers.com/servlet/servlet-jsp-communication/)

Comment: But I want the value of the result only after clicking submit button. Not before that. If I use this I have already a value before clicking submit button.

Comment: @ASHISH After clicking the button,then only servlet gets invoke right ?

Comment: yes after clicking button, servlet get invoked. But in index.jsp It store previous operation value.

Comment: How you are setting the vaule in jsp ??Can you please edit  your post with what you are doing right now ?

Comment: I use only ${res} after submit button and in servlet
request.setAttribute("res", result1);
            RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
            requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

Answer (score 1):

By rendering the desired output in the response. Servlet is a very thin wrapper around HTTP: you are processing an HttpRequest and producing an HttpResponse.