# passing variable from servlet to jsp doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have problem with passing an object from servlet to jsp.

**Servlet.java**

```
    @Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Controller test = new Controller();
    test.setObjects();
    request.getSession().setAttribute("item", test.node_1);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<title> ${item.firstName} </title>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>socialgraphui.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

**Tomcat output**

```
okt 25, 2014 6:17:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deleteRedeployResources
    INFO: Undeploying context []
    okt 25, 2014 6:17:14 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
    INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /Library/Java/Servers/apache-tomcat-7.0.42/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
    okt 25, 2014 6:17:14 PM org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase start
    INFO: The start() method was called on component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] after start() had already been called. The second call will be ignored.
```

In browser console is no error or warning message. Could you please help me how can i find out what is wrong?

Comment: Seems fine to me, does your object has getters for the attribute you are asking or/and are you sure it has the name set?

Comment: @KBorja Actually I am not sure if name of object is set. I tried to debug the application and set a breakpoint in Servlet.java class in doGet method, but it didn't stop at breakpoint. I am new in java ee and i am not sure if doGet method is called after project running.

Comment: @KBoja if object have no getter it will produce javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException for Matt to execute doGet method according your config you should follow this adress 'http://localhost:8080/your project name/Servlet'

Comment: Make a little test, pass one string to the session so you can see if your server is working...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass variables from servlet to jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp)

Comment: @KBorja I tried tmarwen's answer, but result is the same. In title is nothing.

Comment: @Gas Those answers didn't help me

Comment: @njjnex So if I want to execute doGet method, i have to use localhost:8080/my project name/Servlet address? Because i use localhost:8080 address nad when i want to use localhost:8080/my project name/Servlet I got http status 404

Comment: It works with localhost:8080/Servlet address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check URL you follow it should be:

```
http://localhost:8080/your project name/Servlet
```

Also if `item.getFirstName` returns null you will see nothing in  tags

To be sure that your param passing to jsp page change `item` value for String for example

```
request.getSession.setAttribute('item' , 'my title');
```

Now if you will see **my title** in `<title>` tag than passing param done and reason in your object.

Comment: I got http status 404 and yes, in tags is nothing

Comment: If i open http://localhost:8080/your project name/Servlet i get http status 404. For project i use http://localhost:8080/ address

Comment: try <%= session.getAttribute("item") %> and see if that is null or not. if it is not, then as njjnex says, getFirstName may return a null value.

Comment: (your project name) - replace with name of your project

Comment: @Joeblade <%= session.getAttribute("item") %> return null

Comment: @njjnex yes, i replaced it with the name of my project

Comment: please post full url you access this page.

Comment: @njjnex socialgraphui is the name of project, http://localhost:8080/socialgraphui/Servlet

Comment: can you test your 'test.node_1' object I sure it's null

Comment: agree with @njjnex, test the basics first. you can also set a second variable, session.setAttribute("testvalue", "somestring") and try to print that in your page. when in doubt, verify your basic assumptions

Comment: @Joeblade I used wrong address, it works with localhost:8080/Servlet address

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your *JSP* is allowed to access the `Session` request object by setting below parameter on top of your *JSP* page:

```
<%@ page session="true" %>
```

And to avoid HTML illegal chars, it would be better to use [el](/questions/tagged/el):

```
<title>
  <c:out value="${sessionScope.item.firstName}"/>
</title>
```

***Note:*** To use the `c` (core) JSTL, you must import the tag library by declaring below code on top of you *JSP* page:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Comment: I tried it, but result is still the same. In title is nothing.

Comment: Coudl you provide a sample web app and host it in some remote code storage provider, Github may be.
It would be easier to read. You may need to describe what your `item` object referer class is and what `node_1` is!

Comment: I am sorry i tried it with wrong address. It works with localhost:8080/Servlet address

Comment: Could you accept the answer and upvote it if it helped resolving the issue?

Comment: Thanks for help, but actually njjnex's answer helped me solve the problem, but i can at least upvote

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the object in the session scope. So you may wanna use sessionscope to retrive the value:

```
<title>${sessionScope.item.firstName}</title>
```

Comment: Result is the same. In title tag is nothing.