# java servlet rescource dispatcher include html on the right place

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I have a very basic login servlet

```
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        // get request parameters for userID and password
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        if (username.equals("marti") && password.equals("bosch")) {
            response.sendRedirect("login_success.jsp");
        } else {
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    "/login.html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
            out.println("<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>");
            rd.include(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call the servlet it from the login.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"> </p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"> </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

if I input the correct user name and password, the browser correctly renders login_success.jsp. However, when I do not enter the right user name and password, the browser shows the unrendered html as plain text:

```
<font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"> </p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"> </p>
         <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I make the LoginServlet place the message under  in the right place (after the body tag)? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Exactly, you need to put it as a content of an HTML document:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <font color=red>Either user name or password is wrong.</font>
    <form action="LoginServlet" method="post">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username"> </p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password"> </p>
         <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Additionally, a `<font>` tag is deprecated in HTML5.

**EDIT**:

So either you need to `sendRedirect` to the page where an error message is included:

```
response.sendRedirect("login_error.jsp");  //containing exactly the same html I posted
```

Or modify your form JSP, so it renders an additional error message after the authentication failure. You can accomplish that by passing a parameter from a Servlet to JSP. Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp).

Comment: yes, of course, but i mean how can i place this message from the LoginServlet. Concerning the font tag, I just copied the code from a tutorial, when I understand more about Java servlets I'll use right HTML5. Thank you anyway

Comment: Fixed. I misread your question for the first time, apologies :)

Comment: well, from this I guess that there is no way to add some string to a specific position using the out.println() method, which is what I wanted to know. Thanks!