# How to get an object from a Servlet included in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a Servlet that queries the database and creates arraylists (aka the objects).

This Servlet is included in a JSP page that prints the arraylists' content, but I don't know how to pass them from the Servlet to the JSP.

How can I get the JSP to get those objects from the Servlet?

Here is my Servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //CREATING CONTAINERS THAT WILL BE FORWARDED
    ArrayList<Volet> voletList = new ArrayList<Volet>();
    ArrayList<Critere> critereList = new ArrayList<Critere>();
    PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter(); 
    try {  
        //CONNEXION TO DATABASE:
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:oracle", "OCP", "oracle11g");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        //SQL REQUEST
        String sqlVolet = "select * from ocp.volet";
        ResultSet rsVolet = st.executeQuery(sqlVolet);
        //WRITING FROM SQL RESULT INTO CONTAINER LIST:
        while(rsVolet.next())
        {
            Volet volet = new Volet();
            volet.setId(rsVolet.getInt(1));
            volet.setDescription(rsVolet.getString(2));
            voletList.add(volet);
        }

        String sqlCritere = "select * from ocp.critere";
        ResultSet rsCritere = st.executeQuery(sqlCritere);
        while(rsCritere.next())
        {
            Critere critere = new Critere();
            critere.setId(rsCritere.getInt(1));
            critere.setDescription(rsCritere.getString(2));
            critere.setVoletid(rsCritere.getInt(3));
            critereList.add(critere);
        }

        //CLOSING DATABASE CONNEXION:
        con.close();
        //DISPATCH THE CONTAINER THROUGH FORWARD

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher =   request.getRequestDispatcher("/View/ErrorPage.jsp");
        request.setAttribute( "e", e );
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

*P.S. I have tried to forward the objects to the JSP and it didn't work.*

Comment: By using the HttpServletRequest and -Response.

Comment: Please show us what you tried. Especially the servlet code.

Comment: Can you explicit the method a bit more please?

Comment: @Rajesh I have added the code. I want to send the arrayLists.

Comment: use `request.setAttribute()`, just like what you have done in the `catch` block.

Comment: @Kishore Without using the forward method?

Comment: use `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` and refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3609046/1897935

Comment: When I send through setAttribute, it returns the error:
Cannot forward after response has been committed

Comment: what happens if you copy paste the code you have written in catch block, just after "con.close();" (at the end of try block) and set the ArrayList to request scope using "request.setAttribute()". And what you are doing with PrintWriter? Posted code shows nothing.

Comment: You've not set the list in request object and moreover you are not forwarding the list to jsp in try block. code inside catch block will be executed only if an exception is caught

Answer (score 0):

Use request.setAttribute in servlet code

```
request.setAttribute("attributeName",attributeValue);
RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("JSP file path");
reqDispatcher.forward(request,response);
```

and use request.getAttribute in jsp code and type caste it to actual object type.

```
ClassType attributeValue= (ClassType) request.getAttribute("attributeName");
```