# How can i change jsp html link with action style

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

Right now, i have a jsp page that has a tag of something like this :

```
<html:link action="/SequenceA">A</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceB">B</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceC">C</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceD">D</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceE">E</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceF">F</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceG">G</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceH">H</html:link>&nbsp;
<html:link action="/SequenceI">I</html:link>&nbsp;
```

The result would look something like this :

A B C D E F G H I

However, i would like change the style link when its clicked. How can i achieve as when i click on any alphabet, it refreshes and it will unbold everything? For instance if i clicked 'G', the font size of 'G' will increase by 1 and it will become bold. However, right after i clicked 'G', and i clicked 'H', 'G' will be unbold and font size will change back to its normal font size and 'H' will be bold and font size will increase by 1. But due to refresh, it will unbold everything

**Expected result**

When i click on G

A B C D E F **G** H I

After which i click on H

A B C D E F G **H** I

**Current result due to refresh**

A B C D E F G H I

Comment: Is the page actually reloading, or are you using ajax to call the action page ?

Comment: What do you expect? Your a using a link so of course it wants to link to something. What are you trying to achieve here other than the styling you've described? Why are you using links in the first place? you can use javascript and return false on your links to stop the links from working as they are now.

Comment: The page is reloading as the moment an alphabet is clicked, it will go to the database and retrieve all the relevant data corresponds to the alphabet.

Comment: @partypete25 What i am doing now is that i will go to the database and grab whatever data that is correspond to the alphabet (sort of grouping the data). So when i click on the alphabet 'a', i will retrieve all the food from database such as apple, apple pie, apple tarts. When the alphabet 'a' is clicked, it will be bold and font size will be increased by 1. So if alphabet 'b' is clicked, alphabet 'a' will be unbold and font size changed to the original size and the alphabet 'b' will be bold and font size will be increased by 1.

Comment: when you pass back the data, pass back a parameter holding the letter clicked.  In your jsp, query this parameter to know which value to change the style on

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry, how can i do that?

Comment: that question is a bit like *how do I fix a car* - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry, if possible, i would like to stick to my own html code. is there any other way that i can refresh the css after the page is being refreshed?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to add something to the page when it renders to indicate which alphabet letter is currently being viewed. For example if you add an `active` class to that letters link then all you need to do is add this reference in your css.

so if your html output looks like this:

```
<div class="alphabet">
 <a href="/">A</a>
 <a href="/">B</a>
 <a href="/" class="active">C</a>
 ...
</div>
```

your css will look like this:

```
.alphabet a {font-size:12px}
.alphabet a.active {font-weight:bold; font-size:13px;}
```