# JSP JEE getParamater

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I've been trying to get an attribute request(string) in the JSP page but It's just not working, I get null as a result of my URL request:
The servlet code:

```
 @WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        String message = "Transmission de variables : OK !";
        request.setAttribute( "test", message );
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/test.jsp" ).forward( request, response );
        //String attribut = (String) request.getAttribute("test");

    }
```

the JSP :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Ceci est une page généré depuis une JSP.</p>
<p>
<% String attribut = (String) request.getAttribute("test");
   out.println( attribut );
 %>

 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result I get:

```
Ceci est une page généré depuis une JSP.
null
```

Comment: @Nikolas Charalambidis   this is the URL: http://localhost:8282/TestOC/test.jsp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass variables from servlet to jsp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp)

Comment: @Morten Telling It's the only variable I'm using in the servlet

Comment: try please this like localhost:8282/TestOC/test

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt I just tried it and it's not working : the requested resource is not available :/

Comment: Did you put test.jsp into /WEB-INF folder?

Comment: @Gurkan Yesilyurt oups I guess that was the problem I put it in WebContent instead of WEB-INF. thnx you