# Session attribute lost on Wildfly 12

Tags: jsp, httpsession

I am working on legacy project, I am just trying to make it running (it is supposed to work). But I found out a problem with the session in my `JPSs` ( No much settings changed on `standalone.xml`)

Here is login instruction in my servlet `doPost` method:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    try {
        User user = loginService.login(username, password);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user);

    } catch (OAuth2AccessDeniedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
```

**And in my main page**:

```
<%if(session.getAttribute("user")==null){ %>
<html><body><script>window.location.href = "index.html"</script></body></html>
<%}else{
    User user = (User)session.getAttribute("user");
%>
<html>
//rest of html page
```

When I debug, I find that the user is correctly set in the session but in my `jsp` it is null

Comment: What is `session` in main page?

Comment: I think you need `request.getParameter("user");` not `session`

Comment: I added `HttpSession session = request.getSession();` but the debugger crashes there

Comment: learn https://stackoverflow.com/a/3609046/5558072