# In a jsp page, how can I display a long variable value?

Tags: java, jsp

I've calculated the total form submission in the backend, and now I need to display it beside the "total submission" tag on the JSP page.
I've tried a variety of approaches, but nothing seems to be working.
What is the best approach to show the long value on a jsp page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//jsp Page

```
 <dd>Total Submissions:- ${dashboard.totalSubmissions}</dd>
```

//controller

```
long total_submissions = flowSubService.totalSubmissions() + formSubService.totalSubmissions();
 mv.addObject("dashboard", bean);
```

//bean

```
private long totalSubmissions;
getter setter
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually you put the object in the HttpResponse object of the servlet and forward it (read this for an example: [Pass variables from servlet to jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3608891/pass-variables-from-servlet-to-jsp) )

after this in the jsp you get the object (or the value directly) and
<%=valueToShow%>

Answer (score 1):

if the bean is included in your model:

```
<div>
    <dt>Submissions</dt>
    <dt><form:input path="totalSubmissions" readonly="true" /></dt>                    
</div>
```